# My number of guesses wont stop at correct level

Tags: javascript, numbers, getelementbyid, element

I am currently making a minefield game using JavaScript only. I have a problem at the end of the game. I have three difficulty levels so easy gives the user 45 guesses, intermediate 40 guesses and advanced is 35 guesses. However, for some reason when I have it set on intermediate/advanced it keeps going to 45 guesses instead of where it should stop.

After ive spent ages looking at it and changing different things such as the names of the variables and editing code. The guesses were working correctly so each guess actually counted as 1 guess now they are counting as 3. The code is now stopping at 35.

```
var number_of_guesses = 0;
var maximum_guesses = 45;
var intermediate_guesses = 40;
var advanced_guesses = 35;
var number_of_hits = 0;
var number_of_misses = 0;

var element = opener.document.getElementById("easy");
if (element.checked === true)
{
maximum_guesses = 45;
}

var intermediate = opener.document.getElementById("intermediate");
if (element.checked === true)
{
intermediate_guesses = 40;
}

var advanced = opener.document.getElementById("advanced");
if (element.checked === true)
{
advanced_guesses = 35;
}

number_of_guesses++;
if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}

number_of_guesses++;
if (number_of_guesses > intermediate_guesses)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}

number_of_guesses++;
if (number_of_guesses > intermediate_guesses)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}
```

Can someone please tell me:
a) How to make each guess count as 1 instead of 3?
b) How to set each difficulty correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having all three options set the `maximum_guesses` variable, rather than having three different variables for the different difficulties. Then just check that one variable.

```
var number_of_guesses = 0;
var maximum_guesses = 45;
var number_of_hits = 0;
var number_of_misses = 0;
// notice the missing intermediate_guesses and advanced_guesses vars

var element = opener.document.getElementById("easy");
if (element.checked)
{
maximum_guesses = 45;
}

var intermediate = opener.document.getElementById("intermediate");
if (intermediate.checked)
{
maximum_guesses = 40; // changed this to maximum_guesses
}

var advanced = opener.document.getElementById("advanced");
if (advanced.checked)
{
maximum_guesses = 35; // changed this to maximum_guesses
}

number_of_guesses++; // you only need this once
if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}
```

**EDIT**: You also had a typo in that when you were checking wether or not the intermediate and advanced checkboxes were checked, you were still checking the easy element.

**EDIT 2**: Also, in your code, you were calling `number_of_guesses++;` three times, which was why each guess was counting 3 times. For them to only count as one, you only needed the first one. Each time you check, the number will stay the same, so you don't need to increment it three times.

**EDIT 3**: In my code, notice how I removed the `=== false` parts in your if statements where you checked wether or not the checkboxes were checked.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have changed it. My guesses are now counting as 1 instead of 3. When I select intermediate it should stop at 40 but it carries on rising to 45 and when I press advanced it should stop at 35 but again it goes to 45. What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: My code should've fixed that as the intermediate and advanced levels are all modifying the `maximum_guesses` variable, which is then being checked by the last if statement in my code. Did you change the `intermediate_guesses` and `advanced_guesses` to `maximum_guesses` yet?

Comment: Also, you may want to change the `>` signs to `>==`, so that it will stop when the user is **at** 35, 40, or 45 guesses, not just **above** it.

Comment: Yeah the intermediate_guesses and advanced_guesses now show maximum_guesses but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send you the full copy of the code so you can have a look and see why it isnt working?

Comment: Put it on pastebin, and comment a link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8XiTZanh  I have indented the code for the guesses as the other parts are working.

Comment: Yeah il put everything that i have so far and paste it on that

Comment: http://pastebin.com/et2Y9rYA I have put my HTML code at the top and the minefield.js at the bottom

Comment: I don't see your difficulty checkboxes in the code you posted.

Comment: You need to have the difficulty checkboxes in the same file as the actual game itself. The game javascript can't see the radio buttons on the start page, even though they are there in a separate window. Javascript can only see elements in the same window as itself.

Comment: The reason javascript isn't seeing the other window is because your hosting the file locally. Your browser has a same-origin policy, so you must host the files online, both under the same domain for the game window to legally access the other window.

Comment: I have moved the radio buttons onto the page, im trying to get it into a position where it looks best but still the guesses keep going to 45 instead of 40 and 35.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m3Pbm41n I have included the game startup, the game itself and the minefield.js. The problems I have is the difficulties wont set the guess total plus the sound effects dont switch off when I press the button for them to. Hopefully, you will be able to solve the problem

Comment: In your `minefield.js` file, you need to change all of your `opener.document.getElementByID` references to `document.getElementByID`. This will reference the current window, rather than trying to reference the startup window.

Comment: I have tried that still doesnt work. Can you up-vote my question please as it says I need 1 more to talk in a chat. I think this would be better in a chat that like this.

Comment: I have managed to solve part of the problem and I have worked out where the problem is coming from. http://pastebin.com/gUCUm8vt

Comment: As I demonstrated in my answer, you only need to modify one variable. Just make all three of your checks modify one `maximum_guesses` variable

Comment: I have tried that, when I change it all three go to 45 guesses. Easy should stop at 45 guesses, intermediate at 40 guesses and advanced at 35 guesses. I have found a way to make that work. I am just trying to link all three into one

Comment: You have to have the difficulty selected on the *game* page, remove the `opener.` before your `document.getElementById`'s _and_ have all three options modify one variable.

Comment: Can you please send me what you mean on pastebin as im a bit confused. When I have tried this it doesnt work for me but I may have done something wrong